# Change install path to /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin

Tags: python

A simple question, but I have no concrete documentation to confirm my answer.   When installing software with the `make install` command under a unix machine, the default path is going over to `/usr/local/bin`.  I would like to update a package system-wide under `/usr/bin`.  How (and where) do I change the command under `make` or `make install` to `/usr/bin`?

Also - Can the package remain on `/usr/local/bin` but the systemwide usage of Python (the update being installed) be changed to `/usr/local/bin` from `/usr/bin` to avoid modifying the original installed version ?

Comment: Depends on the build system. In a standard GNU autotools: `./configure --prefix=/usr`. This is not recommended, as self compiled and installed software belongs in /usr/local, as to not conflict with things provided by the OS.

Comment: When you install via `make install`, you are not using a package management system, and it is not really appropriate to say that you are installing packages.  You are installing unpackaged software.

Comment: Yes...its unpackaged software.....semantics aside, the default make install defaults to that folder.  what is the command to install over /usr/bin instead?   Or perhaps, to change the system wide env path to point to /usr/local/bin?  To clarify, I'm updating a Python version from 2.4 to 2.7.  Thanks

Comment: @user1678788 - `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: It's already in the PATH as /usr/local/bin.   Although the first list in the PATH is /usr/bin

Comment: Well, this depends on your distribution. Here e.g. it's /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games -- so don't trust it ;)

Answer (score -2):

As far as the install goes, I believe that they’ve handled that pretty well in the comments.

Now for changing the system-wide usage. If it’s available on your OS, [`update-alternatives`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) is great for this.  I am fairly sure that in most cases, the executable in `/usr/bin` is not an executable but rather a soft link to the true Python executable, so changing which version it points to is simply a matter of changing the symlink to point to the version you want to use by default.

Comment: Also, it's rather common to have different version of an executable on a system, be it for testing new version or a package requiring a special old version.